# Does Shannon encoding represent a lower bound on the number of bits needed?

Tags: cryptography, information-theory, entropy

In textbook discussions it is common to characterize Shannon entropy as giving (emphasis added)

> [a **lower bound** on the number of bits ... needed on average to encode symbols drawn from a distribution](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html)

I understand that this is intended to mean, more precisely, that it is average number of bits that will be used by the most efficient (in terms of number of bits) encoding, to encode the symbols in that distribution (or, equivalently, the expected average number of bits for symbols drawn for it).

But is true that the Shanon entropy is a *lower bound*?

For example, if I have 5 symbols with frequencies

$$\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16}$$

the Shanon entropy is $1.95$ (by using 1, 2.4, 3, 3, and 4 bits respectively), but I can encode these symbols as

$$0, 1, 00, 10, 11$$

for an entropy of $1.31$; or (if for some reason the *values* must be distinct) as

$$0,1,10,11,100$$

for an entropy of $1.38$.

Is there some requirement that's placed on the encoding assumed in defining entropy that I'm violating in my examples? Is it true that Shannon encoding represents a lower bound on the number of bits needed?

Comment: It is a lower bound given your probability model. The real challenge is often in creating a good probability model for your source.

Comment: Also you should probably read up on **uniquely decodable codes**

Answer (score 3):

The Shannon entropy represents a lower bound on the average number of bits needed to represent the information symbols **without losing any information**. In other words, the code should be **uniquely decodable**. The examples you gave do not constitute a uniquely-decodable code. For example, how do you decode 010? Is it 0, 1, 0 or 0, 10?

An example of a uniquely-decodable code is 0, 10, 110, 1110, and 1111. With this code, only one sequence represent an encoded sequence. For example, the encoded sequence 01110101111110 correspond to adbec, where a, b, c, d and e represent the uncoded symbols.

Comment: Yes **uniquely decodable code** is good to learn about.

Comment: So, first assumption I'm missing: there's no "delimiter" in the system. Correct?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes, the encoding must be uniquely decodable.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about "uniquely decodable" in this context and what limits it places on the encoding (e.g. what sequences it excludes), with an example? E.g., the calculation in the OP implies that there is a code with 1, 3, 3, 3, and 4 bits that is uniquely decodable (and that there is not any with 1, 2, 3, 3, and 4) right?

Comment: Kindly have a look at some popular encoding methods, such as Huffman code. The basic idea is to be able to decode an encoded sequence properly.  If I denote the original symbols by a, b, c, d, and e having the probabilities you mentioned. Then representing a by 0, b by 10, c by 110, d by 1110 and e by 1111 results in a uniquely decodable code.

Comment: For example, a d c b e will be encoded as 01110110101111. Can you decode the encoded sequence or not?

Comment: That's a d c b e!

Comment: It would be (actually) helpful to clarify explicitly in your answer first that three's no delimiter (the context this is lifted from, machine learning courses, often includes examples that are very concrete but misleading, e.g. [each symbol is communicated on its own](https://rdipietro.github.io/friendly-intro-to-cross-entropy-loss/#entropy)), and then to say a bit more about the requirements that places on relationship among the allowed (unambiguous, decodable) encodings.

Comment: (So my answer to "how do you decode 010" would be that I encounter it as 0  and then 10, or as 0 and then 1 and then 0. Clearly that's not the kind of process assumed in defining entropy.)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing different things. What your "code" achieves is to minimize the quantity $\sum_i p_i l_i$, where $p_i$ and $l_i$ stand for the probability and description length of the source symbol $i$. However, the resulting code is not useful for transmission of information since, as correctly noted by @Math Lover, the generated bit sequences are not uniquely decodable. You should also supply information on what you refer to as "delimiters". Clearly, the delimiter information will require its own "bits" to send, therefore, increase the overall code efficiency.

What we want is to design codes that are uniquely decodable and, also, are *instantaneous*, i.e., one can decode all symbols up to a certain bit in the sequence without having to look at the entire string of bits. Under this condition, the optimal source code again minimizes $\sum_i p_i l_i$ (as you did), however, under the constraint ("Kraft inequality") $\sum_i 2^{-l_i} \leq 1$. This constraint can be shown to be satisfied by every instantaneous code. It is for this constrained optimization problem formulation that the Shannon entropy provides a lower bound on the objective.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, the context here is machine learning, where Shanon entropy is introduced off-handedly, without any mechanistic explanation of how encoded symbols are encountered (or as in the linked example, wrong examples where each symbol is transmitted on its own, and the clearly delimited). So what I'm looking for here is calling out (clearly) some of the (practical) assumptions used in coming up with entropy. So far its clear that there are at least two: (a) no delimiters (that is, nothing indicating the boundaries between symbols) and (b) instantaneous.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Only assumption (b) is considered. Note that an instantaneous code can be obtained by your scheme when delimiter information is also provided at the decoder. Shannon states that the additional bits you would need for representing this delimiter information would result in an overall average code length larger than the entropy. Turns out that the best source codes do not provide *explicit* delimiters.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense (I wondered). But, of course, it all assumes a particular process (e.g. one where the delimiters are as expensive as the bits, or represented using them). Is there any theory around codes where the delimiters and bits have different costs (e.g. if they can have entirely different representations)?

Comment: So (b) implies (a)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I am not aware of any such theory. No (b) does not imply (a) since an instanteneous code could be constructed using *explicit* delimiters. What (b) implies is that the code should necessarily provide delimiters (either explicit or implicit).

Comment: OK, so it's pretty clear why I was puzzled: there are quite a few assumptions about how the code is processed. For example, this definition of entropy does not apply to a scenario where, say, time is not costly and distinct pauses are inserted between transmitted symbols (in which case not only would one of my codes work, but the complexity of the decoding algorithm would be greatly reduced) and critically, it doesn't fit well with where I encountered it; in the context of machine learning, where the encoded entities are discreetly presented (naturally delimited, if you will).

Comment: (That leaves me puzzled as to why entropy is introduced as a *concept* — as opposed to as a just computational convenience — in machine learning courses. But that's a distinct question for another day.)